# How do I render multiple paragraphs taken from mysql table and used in php page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, newline, paragraphs

I have a database and I am using it to create a seminar page.  It holds the seminar information and then when my php page is opened it reads the entries in the database and displays them.

however I am having an issue.  There is a field in my entry form for the abstract of the seminar.  Sometimes they have multiple paragraphs.  When I enter multiple paragraphs into the html form textbox it looks fine.  Also I checked what it looks like once it has been added to the mysql database, it looks fine there as well.  The problem is when I open my more info page and it displays the abstract.  There are no line breaks or tabs.  I have been searching and it appears to be an html issue.

I know what the issue is, but I dont know how to fix it.  Is there an html command that will render the line breaks and tabs?  or perhaps a php command?  Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

edit: to make this post a good reference for others ill post my code

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM seminars WHERE ID = '$ID'"
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
echo $info['abstract'] . "\n "; ?>
}
```

However I used the nl2br function that was recommended and it worked perfectly, it was really simple.  here is the appended code:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM seminars WHERE ID = '$ID'"
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
echo nl2br($info['abstract']) . "\n "; ?>
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Line-breaks have zero semantic meaning in HTML. You need to remap those to `<br>` for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is nl2br(). this will convert all new line characters to 
 tags and create the html space you are looking for.

Something like:

```
echo nl2br($descriptionText);
//$descriptionText being the paragraphs you pulled from the database.
```

Comment: that worked perfectly and I have added the new code to the edit for others to see.  Thank you very much for your help!